# AIC or BIC for model selection in Cox regression (SPSS)

Tags: spss, cox-model, aic

Does anyone know if there is a method (a macro) to calculate AIC or BIC for a model in Cox regression using SPSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no SPSS expert, but you can calculate these yourself if you can retrieve the log-likelihood, which any respectable statistical program using maximum likelihood estimation should do:

$AIC=2k-2loglik$

$BIC=-2loglik+k(ln(n)-ln(2\pi))$

Where *k* is the degrees of freedom, and *n* is the sample size.